# Networking problems: 2 interfaces with 2 gateways, seperated routing tables not working as expected

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, routing

I have a server, running Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS with 2 IP addresses on 2 nics:

```
eth0: 192.168.1.5/24, gw 192.168.1.1    
eth1: 192.168.2.5/24, gw 192.168.2.1
```

As I searched here and on Google, in order to make this work I created a second routing table for eth1, which I added the following:

/etc/iproute2/rt_tables:

```
1 rt2
```

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
post-up ip route add 192.168.2.0/24 dev eth1 src 192.168.2.5 table rt2    
post-up ip route add default via 192.168.2.1 dev eth1 table rt2    
post-up ip rule add from 192.168.2.5/32 table rt2    
post-up ip rule add to 192.168.2.5/32 table rt2
```

I have a pc, which is also connected to 192.168.2.0/24, it has the IP 192.168.2.7.
The problem now is, I cannot reach the server with 192.168.1.5 from my pc.
I ran tcpdump on the server and I know the packet is coming in, but nothing is sent back and no packet is dropped.

I need that 192.168.1.5 is also reachable from my pc.

**Update 1:**

I made a mistake in posting the config here, I updated the last 2 post-up definitions, it should be rule instead of route.(Thx, A.B.)
Secondly, I changed the last sentence, as it was a bit misunderstanding.

Comment: 1st clarification: "via my pc": is the intention that your pc is a gateway (ie a router) between those two networks for other systems on 192.168.2.0/24 ? 2nd clarification: adding a routing table has no effect without adding a rule telling to use this routing table. I see no `ip rule` anywhere

Comment: No my pc shouldn't be a gateway, the pc has 192.168.2.7, the gateway is 192.168.2.1.